# Spring security don't allow my bootstrap Webjars dependency file to load when not authenticated

Tags: java, css, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm new to spring boot and I was creating my new demo E-commerce project to practice on using Spring boot and Thymeleaf

The problem I faced was trying to link bootstrap css files to html in login page while not authenticated yet

Here is my **html link tag**:

```
<link th:rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0-2/css/bootstrap.min.css} "/>
```

My **pom.xml** dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope> 
        </dependency>
```

My **Spring Security Config class**:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    //bcrypt bean definition
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(UserService userService) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setUserDetailsService(userService); //set the custom user details service
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder()); //set the password encoder - bcrypt
        return auth;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(configurer ->
                        configurer.requestMatchers("/register/**",
                                               "/css/**",
                                               "/js/**",
                                               "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(form ->
                        form
                                .loginPage("/showLoginPage")
                                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateUser")
                                .permitAll()
                )
                .logout(logout -> logout.permitAll()
                )
                .exceptionHandling(configurer ->
                        configurer.accessDeniedPage("/access-denied")
                );

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Most of the solutions used ***authorizeRequests().antMatchers()*** which is deprecated.
Also, if anyone noticed any other mistakes please guide me as I said I'm new to Spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem was not annotating **SecurityConfig** class with **@EnableWebSecurity**.

Here is my SecurityConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity // <------------ That was missing
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(configurer ->
                        configurer.requestMatchers("/register/**",
                                        "/","/webjars/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

I also changed my pom.xml to use bootstrap 4.6.2

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
            <version>0.40</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Finally, This is how I imported bootstrap in thymeleaf html

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}" type="text/css"/>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
```